# Allow read of firestore document, if it does not exist

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In Firestore I wan't to allow a read, *if the targeted document does not exists*. I have tried the following:

```
service cloud.firestore {
   match /databases/{database}/documents {

     match /reports/{report} {
        allow read: if !exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/reports/{report});
     }

   }
}
```

It does not work, the respons is: `Missing or insufficient permissions.`.

Comment: Interesting, when would you need to allow a read to a document that doesn't exist?

As for the rule, you need to use `$(report)` instead of `{report}`. See the note about escaping variables here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will try it out. I am creating a CRUD application, with a list and details view in Angular with angularfire2. If the user wants to create a new item, I can use the angularfire2 SDK to create a unique ID. When I then navigate to the details page, I provide this ID. Then I "expect" firestore to just return an empty result instead of permission denied. I hope it makes sense :)

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding you, I don't think you need this extra rule to check read permissions for an empty collection. If your user has permission to read the `reports` collection, then Firestore should behave as you expect: for an empty collection, it'll return an empty result instead of a permission denied error.

Comment: But it is not an empty collection. Lets say that we have a reports collection, with multiple documents. Now the user clicks add-report button in the list component, angularfire2 generates a client side key new document, and the router navigates to the detail component. BUT before loading the details component, the component will try to load this specific document from the collection.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be working.

```
allow get: if resource == null;
```

Answer (score -1):

In case you're doing this server-side, you might instead query the document's existence using the [admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) (firestore rules are only applied to the client SDK):

```js
const snapshot = await adminFirestore.doc('reports/non-existent-item').get();
if (!snapshot.exists) {
  // handle gracefully
}
```